# Do white cats prefer to hang out on light-colored objects?

Tags: cats, behavior

We've only had black cats and our past and present cats seem to like to hang out on dark-colored objects (e.g. navy blankets, gray sweatshirts, etc.). They are often difficult to see there and we always assumed that was their intent. But we're wondering how true that is. Do cats seek out spots that make them harder to see? In particular, do they choose areas that match their coats, indicating knowledge of their own coloring? For example, do white cats prefer to hang out on light-colored objects?

Comment: I'm pretty sure my cat with light gray hair seeks out my dark colored shirts for the sole reason that his hairs show up so well on them.

Answer (score 4):

You might have your cats on dark objects because dark objects absorb more light and convert it to heat... thus being slightly warmer.

I've never noticed my cats trying to "blend in".  Sometimes they like to hide, or find places that are cozy, but when they are in the open they never act like "you can't see me" (I have seen that behavior from an octopus which did try to blend in, but never from cats)

Comment: Thanks for the response and insight. I hadn't considered the "dark things are warmer" possibility because the dark objects our cat likes to sit on aren't in direct light - my IR thermometer shows adjacent light and dark sweatshirts at the same temperature, with the cat on the dark one - but I suppose cats could still *think* it will be warmer.

Comment: I have an orange cat and a camel-colored leather sofa. Complete camouflage. He loves it.

Comment: I doubt cats have that level of intelligence